# Invoking a method in a class C#

Tags: c#, forms, navigation, frame, wpf

I am writing my **first** app using C# and XMAL/WPF.

There is a MainWindow.xml that has a frame. I then added new pages (page1.xaml and page2.xaml).

MainWindow.xaml initially loads content of page1. There is button on Page1 that navigates to Page2.

I'd like run a few lines of code on Page2. This is where I am having a problem.
If I create a method in Page2 and and call it (out side constructor, right after it), it does not work.

Error I get is below.

I have to call it inside Page2 constructor for it to execute; however, the code runs right after click on the button in Page1.

It works, but windows still show Page1, and navigates to page2 after executing the commands.

I would like Page2 to load up first, and then execute the lines:

```
// button on page1
private void nextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Page2 p2= new Page2();
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(p2);
        }
```

If I add code outside the constructor (right after constructor) 
I get the following error:

> Invalid token 'while' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// add this line to your page2 class constructor
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
```

Then,

```
 void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     while(true)
     { // any loop you want
     }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks @deeiip it works. But commands in `MainWindow_Loaded` execute before page2 loads. I want to load page2, so I can see the content of page2, and then execute the command. Right now, it waits till all of the commands are done execute and then shows page2 content.